# Automate the new spring initiated beans to be added to the application

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a shopping-cart application

I have created one product bean and all the new products are being added  through spring context
given below

```
<bean id="product1" class="entities.Product">
    <property name="name" value="product1" />
</bean>
<bean id="product2" class="entities.Product">
    <property name="name" value="product2" />
</bean>
.....
```

My product team is adding one bean in the spring context every-time they have a new product

I am getting the bean using the following code

```
Product product = (Product) context.getBean("product1");
Product product2 = (Product) context.getBean("product2");
```

but every time they add the product I need to change my code to my display product set

How can I automate so that I can know number of product in the XML before hand
or have every new product handled automatically

I am using this currently which is working fine but I am sure there is better solution to it

```
Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();
    int i=1;

        while(true){
            try{
            products.add((Product) context.getBean("product"+i));
            }
            catch(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException n){
                System.out.println(n);
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }



    for(Product p : products)
        System.out.println(p.getName());
```

Comment: Why do you need beans for each product?

Comment: Simply declare a list of products and retrieve that list.

Comment: @Alex Maybe the application has no database at all.

Comment: yes there is no Database . @Brat: the product list keeps on changing we do not want to change the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `context.getBeanNamesForType(Product.class)` to get the names of beans of specified type.
eg:

```
String names[] = context.getBeanNamesForType(Product.class);
for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
  products.add((Product) context.getBean(names[i]));
```

More on [getBeanNamesForType](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use, instead, [getBeansOfType()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansOfType%28java.lang.Class%29) method that returns a Map: the key is the name of the bean, the value is the bean instance:

```
    Map map = context.getBeansOfType(Product.class);
    for (Iterator iterator = map.keySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        String beanName = (String) iterator.next();
        System.out.println(beanName + " for bean instance: " + map.get(beanName));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependency injection for that. In your class where you need to `Product` instances simple put a field which is a collection (`List<Product>`, `Set<Product>` or `Map<String,Product>`) or an array (`Product[]` and put `@Autowired` or `@Inject` on that field.

```
public MyClass {

    @Autowired
    private List<Product> products;

}
```

This will instruct the application context to inject all beans of the type `Product` into that collection. Now in the method where you need it you can simply access the collection.

As explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation) in the reference guide.